# Применение Serializable

Tags: java, android, serializable

Наткнулся на следующий вопрос, а именно отличия между `Parcelable` и `Serializable` , немного углубившись в этот вопрос сделал вывод что лучше конечно использовать `Parcelable` так как он быстрее ну и относительно не сложен.
Единственное что нам нужно сделать, это имплементировать сам интерфейс с его методами и в intent можно спокойно работать следующим образом:

```
 object = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("ключик");
```

Но всё таки, есть ли применение где то и для Serializable?
+ какие дополнения к нему нужны, помимо простого имплементирования интерфейса?

Answer (score 2):

`Serializable` == `Parcelable`. Вся суть в том, что второе это адаптация под андроид первого - механизм тот же, оптимизированный под мобильную разработку.

Вы можете использовать сериализацию - никто не мешает. Но **лучше** использовать `Parcelable`.

Вся разница - просто в оптимизации. А так - тот же интерфейс-маркер.

upd
Пример:

```
  public void SerializeMethod(){ 
        Person mPerson = new Person(); 
        mPerson.setName("Leon"); 
        mPerson.setAge(25); 
        Intent mIntent = new Intent(this,ObjectTranDemo1.class); 
        Bundle mBundle = new Bundle(); 
        mBundle.putSerializable(SER_KEY,mPerson); 
        mIntent.putExtras(mBundle); 
        startActivity(mIntent); 
    }
```

[Источник](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/01/android-tutorial-two-methods-of-passing-object-by-intent-serializableparcelable.html)

Comment: Я привёл пример кода для parceable как это делается в Serializable?

Comment: @Inkognito обновил

Comment: Serializable  добавляет метаданные лишние, а Parcelable нет

Comment: @Asgard спасибо за ответ, но простой заменой на putSerializable у меня не получается. Мол невозможно реализовать данный метод